# $f(x)=2x+\cot^{–1}x+\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}−x)$ increasing or decreasing in $\mathscr{R}$.

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Show that $f(x)=2x+\cot^{–1}x+\log(\sqrt{1+x^2}−x)$ is increasing in $\mathscr{R}$.

**My Attempt**
$$
f'(x)=2-\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}−x}\\
=2-\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{\frac{x-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}−x}\\
=2-\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
=\frac{2(1+x^2)-1-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}\\
=\frac{1+2x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}
$$
How do I show that $1+2x^2\geq\sqrt{1+x^2}\implies f'(x)\geq 0$ and thus the given function is increasing in $\mathscr{R}$ ?

Comment: The problem is, that e.g. for x=0 inequality doesn't hold but equality holds.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош $2$ is cancelled by the $2$ in the denominator while differentiating the square root.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my mistake, I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $x\neq0$, $$1+2x^2>\sqrt{1+x^2}\impliedby1+4x^2+4x^4>1+x^2\impliedby 4x^4+3x^2>0$$